# Angular still outputs 401 error on console even with interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, interceptor, subscribe

These three methods defines how I handle the login.

```
// Component.
onLogged() {
    this.auth.login(this.user).subscribe({
        next: (data: any) => {
            console.log('Connection established.');
            
            let token = data.headers.get('Authorization')!;
            
            this.auth.saveToken(token);
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
    });
}

// Auth Service.
login(user: User) {
    console.log('Connecting...');
    return this.http.post<User>(this.url + '/login', user, {observe: 'response'});
}

// Interceptor.
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    if (token) {
        // Adds token to header.
        request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }});
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if ([401, 403].includes(error.status)) { console.log('Access denied to the ressource.'); }
            
            return EMPTY;
        })
    );
}
```

However I still have a 401 error on console, even with the interceptor and the return EMPTY block.
I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, or what I am missing.

I searched recent topics on the same issues but they are already too outdated!
I really appreciates if someone could help me! :)

Comment: Is your interceptor properly registered and being called?

Comment: @AdrianBrand My interceptor is being registered using the providers : `providers: [ {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true} ],` which contains my intercept() method. It is apparently being called as expected.

Comment: Are you looking at the request in the browsers dev tools? Is the header there? Have you tested the token with Postman?

Comment: @AdrianBrand Yes, it shows 401 on this line `this.auth.login(this.user).subscribe({...` and request using postman returns 401 with `{ "error": "Bad credentials" }` in body, the header is present. also, sorry for the delay!

Comment: If it still errors in Postman then it is your API and nothing to do with Angular

Comment: I am using my custom authentication failure handler, that sets the status, content and writes the response back, could it be the way I return my response from my spring security filters, that triggers the 401 the « wrong way » ?